# Script to pick random directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell, random, parameters

I have a directory full of directories containing exam subjects I would like to work on randomly to simulate the real exam.

They are classified by difficulty level:

```
0-0, 0-1 .. 1-0, 1-1 .. 2-0, 2-1 ..
```

I am trying to write a shell script allowing me to pick one subject (directory) randomly based on the parameter I pass when executing the script (0, 1, 2 ..).

I can't quite figure it, here is my progress so far:

```
ls | find . -name "1$~" | sort -r | head -n 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly is `-name "1$~"` expected to match? Do you mean `-name "$1*"`?

Comment: `IFS= read -r -d '' name < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "$1*" -type d -print0 | shuf -z -n 1) && printf '%q\n' "$name"` is another approach that *does* use external tools, if you're on a GNU system and so are guaranteed to have `shuf` and `find -print0`. The use of `-print0` and `shuf -z` prevents misbehavior with unusual filenames -- you wouldn't want someone to `mkdir -p $'foo\n/etc/passwd\n/bar'` and then have your command emit `/etc/passwd` (granted, that particular example would require the `-maxdepth 1` to be removed as well).

Comment: Related: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for any external commands (`ls`, `find`, `sort`, `head`) for this at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o nullglob       # make globs expand to nothing, not themselves, when no matches found
dirs=( "$1"*/ )       # list directories starting with $1 into an array

# Validate that our glob actually had at least one match
(( ${#dirs[@]} )) || { printf 'No directories start with %q at all\n' "$1" >&2; exit 1; }

idx=$(( RANDOM % ${#dirs[@]} ))  # pick a random index into our array
echo "${dirs[$idx]}"             # and look up what's at that index
```

Comment: Thank you very much Charles for all your answers on this post. This might be simpler (not using external commands) but it looks like chinese to me haha, what is it exactly and where can I learn more? I naturally ended up using what you call external commands when looking for answers..

Comment: Is there a specific part you're curious about? `dirs=( "$1"/* )` is an [array](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) with a [glob expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) in it; `${#dirs[@]}` is how you get the length of an array; `${dirs[$idx]}` is how you get a specific item out of an array; `$(( ))` creates an [arithmetic context](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), in which `%` has the same meaning it has in C, taking the remainder. Anything else that's unclear?

Comment: BTW, if you're looking for good quality documentation, I advise the [official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/), the [bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/), or the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide); steer clear of documentation created by TLDP, particularly the ABS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into all of your links